# MySQL Tricky query

Tags: mysql

I have two tables

```sql
TABLE1 : ID(PRIMARTY-INT) COLUMN1(CHAR),LAST_MODIFIED TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;

TABLE2 : ID(INT) COLUMN1(CHAR)
```

`TABLE2` contains about 1000 records.

If I use

```
REPLACE INTO TABLE1(ID,COLUM1) SELECT ID,COLUMN FROM TABLE2
```

then `LAST_MODIFIED` will be updated even if previous record is same.

If I use `INSERT`, it will give an error on duplicate record.

If I use `INSERT IGNORE`, it won't update the record.

What I want: update/add new values and also update `LAST_MODIFIED` value if new values are not same as old values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
REPLACE INTO TABLE1(ID,COLUM1) 
SELECT TABLE2.ID,TABLE2.COLUMN 
FROM TABLE2
INNER JOIN TABLE1 on (TABLE1.ID = TABLE2.ID) AND (TABLE1.COLUMN <> TABLE2.COLUMN)
```

or you could try this:

```
UPDATE table1 SET 
  table1.field1 = table2.field1 
   .... 
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 on table1.id = table2.id
```

Comment: i have 100 columns :-(... is there any other appraoch

Comment: May be then you could try this:
UPDATE table1 SET
table1.field1 = table2.field1
....
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 on table1.id = table2.id

Comment: 100 columns sounds like poor design. May want to address that if possible.